# Hibernate: why c3p0 timeout not working?

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, session, c3p0

I work on web java application using hibernate, and i always get memory low errors for tons of java inactive sessions on my oracle db. i tried to closing this unused sessions with c3p0 timeout config but it's not working at all.
this is my hibernate config and my open sessions after several minutes:
(the commented code below is for when i tried using common dbcp refer to one of answers for similar questions and timeout times set to 30 seconds for test.)

```
<property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:test</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">tams_test</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">test1234</property>
    <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
    <property name="hibernate.transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransactionFactory</property>  
    <property name="hibernate.connection.isolation">2</property>
    <property name="org.hibernate.flushMode">COMMIT</property>
    <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">false</property>
    <property name="hibernate.transaction.auto_close_session">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.order_updates">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.order_inserts">true</property>
    <!--  <property name="hibernate.dbcp.initialSize">3</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dbcp.maxIdle">50</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dbcp.minIdle">0</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dbcp.maxWait">180000</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dbcp.maxConnLifetimeMillis">30000</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dbcp.defaultQueryTimeout">1</property>-->
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">1</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">150</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">50</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">30</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">30</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idleConnectionTestPeriod">30</property>
    <property name="c3p0.testConnectionOnCheckout">true</property>
    <property name="testConnectionOnCheckin">true</property>
    <property name="c3p0.maxConnectionAge">30</property>
    <property name="maxIdleTimeExcessConnections">30</property>
    <property name="connection.provider_class">
        org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider
    </property>
```

open sessions on oracle db after several minutes
[image]

Comment: I faced this problem too, did you resolve it?

Comment: Can you show your dataSource bean?

Answer (score 0):

I faced your problem too, and hibernate didn't want to apply my parameters of c3p0, so I changed my datasource and it completly solved my problem of inactive sessions.

Try to setup your dataSource bean like this:

```
 <bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClass" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"/>
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@xxxx:1521:xxx"/>
    <property name="user" value="xx"/>
    <property name="password" value="xxxx"/>

    <property name="maxStatements" value="1000"/>
    <property name="maxIdleTime" value="30"/>
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="100"/>
    <property name="minPoolSize" value="10"/>
    <property name="initialPoolSize" value="10"/>
    <property name="idleConnectionTestPeriod" value="20"/>

</bean>
```